# Retrieve databound object for selected row in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Currently, I'm retrieving the actual databound object of the selected row from a datagrid(WPF) in this fashion:

```
private void PointListDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PointItem pointItem = (sender as DataGrid).CurrentItem as PointItem;
}
```

It works, but this is inelegant and it requires me to cast twice.

Treeview had an SelectedItemChanged event which allowed me to retrieve the databound object from the event argument, but I couldn't find a way to do the same thing for DataGrid.

How do I retrieve the databound object for the selected row?

Comment: Hi, just a quick question but why are you not using MVVM Pattern? That would make it easier to retrieve the databound object of the selected row in the datagrid.

Comment: This is a project that was recently delegated to me which was started few years ago, so I had no option to make it MVVM. Although I am also curious how using the MVVM pattern would make this task easier. You still have to catch the event and get the databound object somehow, no?

Comment: You won't have to catch events when you're using MVVM's because you can just bind the SelectedItem of the DataGrid and get its databound object directly.

Comment: @oldStackExchangeInstance That's just plain databinding though, nothing that you can't do without MVVM. Also, I need to catch the selected even as I'm doing some other work with it on the UI.

Comment: Then I would recommend using Caliburn.Micro framework Message.Attach if you want to catch the selected event to the ViewModel. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just add a property of type PointItem to your DataContext class (for example the Window or Page class that contains the DataGrid) and bind the CurrentItem property to this property. Then  the Data Binding handles the casting for you and you won't have to do it manually:

```
    public PointItem CurrentPointItem
    {
        get { return (PointItem)GetValue(CurrentPointItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentPointItemProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentPointItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPointItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentPointItem", typeof(PointItem), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

and your xaml (of course you would have to set the DataContext property of the DataGrid or one of its parents to the object that contains the CurrentPointItem property):

```
<DataGrid CurrentItem={Binding CurrentPointItem} />
```

Than you can write your event like this:

```
private void PointListDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PointItem pointItem = CurrentPointItem;
    if (pointItem == null)
    {
        //no item selected
    }
}
```